# Switching runlevel when moving /var to another partition

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, partition

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and I would like to move /var to another partition using a python script. I found [some directions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/post-installation-re-partitioning-how-to-move-var-199391/#post1019938) that I thought were pretty good, but they call for switching to runlevel 1 (single-user mode) to prevent changes to /var while it is moved.

Is switching the runlevel necessary? Do I just call `os.system('init 1')` directly in my script? Can I put the system back in its normal state just by calling `os.system('init 2')` after the script is done?

When I'm connected over SSH I get booted out when I run `init 1` myself, even if I'm connected as root. If I'm at the keyboard when I do `init 1` I get the message: `Will now switch to single-user mode, Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue):`. My root password does not work at that point so I've tried `Control-D` and logging in as a user. `runlevel` then says the system is back at runlevel 2, but I can't reconnect by SSH until I reboot the system.

Any help understanding what is going on is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For moving `/var` as a whole, I'd recommend booting from a live CD (or USB) unless you're very confident in what you're doing (and if you were, you wouldn't be asking this question).

Separating `/var` isn't particularly useful anyway. If your `/` partition is almost full, look for a large directory or two that you can move away more easily, such as `/var/www` or `/var/mail` or `/var/cache`. Oh, and run `apt-get clean` to make sure you're not worrying over a large amount of downloaded and installed `.deb` packages.

Comment: It's a web server on a virtual host, so I'm wary of overflowing log files and such. I don't think I would be able to do the live boot. Thanks for the tip on `apt-get clean` though.